# Vim colors in tty terminal

Tags: linux, vim, color-scheme, tty

I was wondering how can I make vim custom colorschemes to work in tty terminals with 8 colors (the `ctrl+alt+fx` one).

I'm using **molokai** theme for vim (code [here](https://github.com/vladtarniceru/vim-config/blob/master/molokai.vim))

Right now, when I open vim in tty, it appears only as light blue instead of 8 colors, if I select **molokai**..

It was working yesterday, but I think I changed some file and I messed it up.

So, tell me please what should I do to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I don't keep every file under git. So probably I erased something which was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to duplicate the "256 colors" block:

```
if &t_Co > 255
    " color definitions
endif
```

in order to create an "8 colors" block:

```
if &t_Co == 8
    " color definitions
endif
```

and edit every color value in that new block according to `:h cterm-colors`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best answer, but since you are, wisely, using revision control, why don't you do :

```
git diff <working-commit> <non-working commit>
```

You can even do a `git bisect`, and find the issue by yourself ?

Comment: I'm not using git for every folder I have. And I don't know why it worked yesterday and today doesn't, I just think that I erase something (which was not kept in git)..

Comment: Ok, fair enough, it makes sense, but you might mention it in your question that youre change is likely not under revision control, if not someone is going to be looking intensely at your git log on github.